# Sum up unique counts by sample in a data.frame using R

Tags: r

I have a tab delimited table that looks like this (its huge, with the entries in "source" column going all the way to 10 million rows):

```
source    Bin1    Bin2    Bin3    Bin4    Bin5
  A         1       1       2       2       3
  B         1       1       1       1       1
  C         0       0       0       1       0
  D         0       0       2       0       0
  E         4       0       0       1       0
  F         1       0       1       2       1
  G         0       5       0       0       0
```

I want to get two things from this table using R (or perl): 
(1) the sum of shared entries equal or greater than 1; 
(2) unique entries for each column "Bin1-5" based on the "source" column in relative to all other bins

In this case the sum of shared entries based on "source" would 2 (irrespective of whether a bin has more than one entry)

The unique counts of entries per "Bin" against all others Bins should be

```
Bin1    Bin2    Bin3    Bin4    Bin5    
0       5       2       1       0
```

Comment: I'm really having trouble understanding what you want to compute. Would you mind explaining further what `sum of shared entries` should be and why it would be `2` in this example? Same with `unique counts of entries per bin`, what exactly shall be counted?

Comment: Leo, what I am trying to get are the elements in each row (based on column 1 = "source") that are common to all Bins. Here, it doesn't matter if the elements/values are 1 to n (not zeros); for example A & B are present in all Bins so they count as 2 elements. Secondly, I want to get the sum of values of unique elements present in only one Bin relative to all the others (i.e., column Bin1 vs. Bin2 vs. Bin3 vs. Bin4 vs. Bin5 ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame("source" = LETTERS[1:7], "Bin1" = c(1,1,0,0,4,1,0), "Bin2" = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,5), "Bin3" = c(2,1,0,2,0,1,0),
             "Bin4" = c(2,1,1,0,1,2,0), "Bin5" = c(3,1,0,0,0,1,0), row.names = 1)

colSums(df[rowSums(df > 0) == 1, ])
```

`df > 0` turns your data into a logical array, if you sum the rows (`rowSums`) and find where it is equal to 1, you get an array of which rows contain only one value. Then calculate the sum of the columns (`colSums`) of these roles. 
With ten million rows it may be necessary to perform this operation on blocks of your data, and generate a cumulative summation.

Comment: Thanks Lespied, but this doesn't work. I get following error already.    Error in colSums(df[rowSums(df > 0) == 1, ]) : 'x' must be numeric
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: see the updated table command, i used the source columsn as rownames rather than an explicit column. it would be easier to change the command if this was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, partial answer for the sum of shared entries.

```
df <- data.frame("source" = LETTERS[1:7], "Bin1" = c(1,1,0,0,4,1,0), "Bin2" = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,5), "Bin3" = c(2,1,0,2,0,1,0),
               "Bin4" = c(2,1,1,0,1,2,0), "Bin5" = c(3,1,0,0,0,1,0))

sum_of_shared_entries <- length(which(apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) all(x > 0))))

> sum_of_shared_entries
[1] 2
```

Edit: Sum of the rows can be obtained with:

```
colsum_of_shared_entries <- colSums(df[which(apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) all(x > 0))), -1])

> colsum_of_shared_entries
Bin1 Bin2 Bin3 Bin4 Bin5 
  2    2    3    3    4
```

Answer to second part of your question: Sum of unique counts per bin can be obtained with:

```
sum_of_unique_counts <- colSums(df[which(lapply(apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) which(x > 0)), length) == 1),-1])

> sum_of_unique_counts
Bin1 Bin2 Bin3 Bin4 Bin5 
   0    5    2    1    0
```

Somebody might revisit the code of the second part, I may have gotten lost in the combination of `which` and `apply`. This might be possible with less code, but at least it works like this. The solution

Comment: Great Leo, that worked for the first problem! Supposing I want also to get the total values of these "sum_of_shared_entries" per bin. By simple calculation for bins 1 to 5, these would be 2, 2, 3, 3, and 4 respectively. How can I add that into your code (besides the second previous question).

Comment: Quick work Leo! I see that you define the columns/rows in colSums(df[which(apply(df[,2:6] ... "the [,2:6] in all cases. Must this be explicitly defined?

Comment: I just simplified the solution so you don't need to change your `0` to `NA`. The `[,2:6]` can be better expressed by `[,-1]` to ignore the `source`-column, changing it now.

Comment: Alright, should work pretty well now. Getting lunch, will be back soon if you have more questions/somethings not working.

Comment: Thanks Leo. Bon appetite! When you come back, seems there is incorrect number of dimensions in the column definition  "Error in df2[, -1] : incorrect number of dimensions" CORRECTION I found the error: df2 should be "df".

Comment: I changed df2 to "df" in your last revision.  sum_of_unique_counts <- colSums(df[which(lapply(apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) which(x > 0)), length) == 1),-1])

Comment: Changed it in the code, thanks for noticing. Does the answer solve all your questions now? If so, you might consider accepting it :)